# How can I make vim format numbered lists with correct indentation?

Tags: vim

This question is related to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282355/how-to-get-vim-to-format-bulleted-lists-with-correct-indentation), but I have reached a bit of a stumbling block in trying to get the same behavior with numbered lists.

As a reference, here is what the configuration looks like in the previous question:

```
set formatoptions=tcq
set comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:- 
set autoindent
```

I read the output of `:help comments` and jumped to also read `format-comments`. Based on that page, it seemed that I needed to add some expression with the flag `fb` to represent numbered lists. I tried the following.

```
set comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-,fb:\d\+.
```

It did not throw any errors, but it also did not have any noticeable effect.
In particular, the sample text looks the same before and after `gq`.

```
1. This is a numbered list item that has been wrapped. The second line is not
indented as desired.
```

The desired output looks like this:

```
1. This is a numbered list item that has been wrapped. The second line is not
   indented as desired.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read `:help 'formatoptions'` and follow the link to `:help fo-table`, then you will find the `n` option that does exactly what you want:

```
:set fo+=n
```

The `'comments'` option does exactly what the docs say, and they do not mention that any part of it can be a general pattern, so I am not surprised that adding `\d` did not help.

@kev's answer mentions the `'formatlistpat'` option, but the setting he recommends is already the default.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `:help 'formatlistpat'`:

```
:set tw=80
:set flp=^\\s*\\d\\+[\\]:.)}\\t\ ]\\s*
```

Comment: I checked the value of `flp` and it indeed matches the default.

Comment: However, I may need to use this for numbered lists like `(1)`, so please don't delete this answer.